# Load assembly from custom location by altering the default CLR probing order

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

I have an application that contains all of its dependencies on the same directory as the application so everything works well. However, I would like to be able to load the assemblies from a custom location on-demand. The location is known before the start of the application but the important point is that assemblies should be loaded from the custom location **even if they are present in the app base directory**.

Here are a few things I tried:

#### Method 1: Add directory to the private probing path

```
// This method does not work for assemblies outside the app directory. Also, it ignores the private path if the assembly is present in the app directory
        private static void ConfigureCustomAssemblyLoading1(string directory)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(directory);
        }
```

#### Method 2: By hooking up to assembly resolution event

```
// The AssemblyResolve event is only fired if the resolution fails, so the assembly will not be loaded from custom path if present in app directory
        private static void ConfigureCustomAssemblyLoading2(string directory)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var requestedAsm = args.Name.Split(',')[0];
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var asm = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                    if (asm.Equals(requestedAsm))
                        return Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                }

                return null;
            };
        }
```

#### Method 3: using codebase tag in config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Calculator"/>
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"
                  href="file://C:\test\Calculator.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

This takes precedence over the local app base directory, however, since there are hundreds of dependent assemblies, this is not a convenient solution. If I could just specify the probing directory, it would have solved the problem.

Below is a sample program to try this out:

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string customDirectory = @"C:\test"; // force load assembly from here
            //ConfigureCustomAssemblyLoading1(customDirectory);
            ConfigureCustomAssemblyLoading2(customDirectory);
            CalculateSum();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CalculateSum()
        {
            var sum = CustomMath.Sum(1, 1);
            Console.WriteLine($"In case you do not know, sum of 1 and 1 is {sum}");
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem with Solution 2? I use it in a similar scenario and it appears to work.

Comment: @PMF The AssemblyResolve is only fired when the resolution of a given assembly fails. In my case, since the assemblies are already present in the application directory, CLR loads it from there and this event is never fired.

Comment: In a very similar scenario I'm working with, that appears to not be the case. I get a call to my resolver, even if the assembly is in the same directory as the exe. How do you load the assemblies? Are they strong-named (signed)?

Comment: @PMF That's interesting. Even the documentation of the AssemblyResolve event says "Occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails." So I actually expect it to not fire when the CLR is able to resolve the assembly reference from the application directory. 
btw, my assemblies are not signed. Can you think of any explanation for the behavior you notice in your case?

Comment: Well, two theories: 1) My assemblies are signed. And 2) I load them dynamically (using `Assembly.Load()` and if that fails `Assembly.LoadFrom()`. Can you show the code that loads the assemblies?

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I don't load them explicitly using any of the Assembly.Load() overloads. I guess you might be only using reflection to call the assembly's methods? Mine is a regular application with static reference to the dependencies and are copied over to the application directory where CLR loads them automatically. What I want is a switch which if enabled, allows me to load the assemblies from another location instead.
The sample I posted should be enough to replicate the problem. It just needs a CustomMath class with Sum method defined in another class library.

Comment: I see. Then that's your problem, actually. .NET assemblies are not intended to be replaced by a different implementation after a static build. Signing assemblies is de-facto mandatory, and therefore replacing them is not possible. Consider a design which uses reflection and/or an interface abstraction layer instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do not intend to replace the already loaded assemblies at runtime. Usually, your static reference could be from anywhere and CLR probes the assemblies in a particular order (the assemblies need not reside at the same location from where static reference was made).
In fact, I am very close to the solution I need with the <codebase> element, just that I need it at the directory level rather than the assembly level.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above in the comments, you are not supposed to replace libraries that were statically linked during build. This *might* work if the assemblies are not strong-named (not signed), but it is not guaranteed to work and bad practice in the .NET world. Code signing is not only a way of ensuring the code was not manipulated, but also to make sure the build is consistent and you're not accidentally mixing libraries from different builds. Problems in your build could otherwise cause undefined behavior if libraries are not matching the expected version.

If libraries need to be loaded dynamically (which as-such, is completely valid), use Reflection with a common interface layer in a shared assembly.

Comment: Apologies, if I did not make the requirements clear. This has nothing to do with signing since I do not intend to replace it with a differently versioned assembly (signed or unsigned)
All I want to do is to load an assembly from a configurable location. It can have the exact same signing and version info as the static bind.
You may argue that it is extremely bad practice to have two assemblies with exactly the same version having different code but I only need it for non-production needs and didn;t mention it since I don't want to diverge from the main topic

Comment: I understand your requirement, but I think you really should consider changing your concept. You're trying to apply a hack to get things done, which might work for a while, but is likely to break sometime, because the system was not designed to do it the way you want it. My answer above is just a recommendation; if you want to do it differently, that's your call.

Comment: Note that two signed assemblies with different code, even if they expose the exactly same methods, are not identical.